# Что нужно заключить в RegExp, чтобы replace() заменял нужную часть найденной подстроки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Собственно, есть регэксп. Допустим: `/( |<)привет/g`. Он должен отбирать все "привет", идущие после пробела или "<". Если подставить эту регулярку в replace(), то заменятся, разумеется, не подстроки "привет", а " привет" или "<привет".

```
console.log('привет<привет'.replace(/( |<)привет/g, 'пока'));        //приветпока
```

Вопрос: возможно ли сделать регулярку такой, чтобы получилось "привет<пока" - то бишь, чтобы некоторые символы только искались, но не входили в соответствие. Как, например, специальный символ \b.

Comment: `console.log('привет<привет'.replace(/([\s<])привет/g, '$1пока'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте захватывающую подмаску и обратную ссылку:

```js
console.log('привет<привет'.replace(/([\s<])привет/g, '$1пока'));
// => привет<пока
```

- `([\s<])` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: любой пробельный символ или символ `<`
- `привет` - подстрока.

`$1` — это обратная ссылка на текст в буфере первой подмаски.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @АртемВагин Рад помочь. Пожалуйста, поставьте +1 и галочку слева.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [look behind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Other_assertions), но это относительно недавнее добавление, поддерживается не во всех браузерах и версиях Node.js:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Lookbehind-Assertions

```js
console.log('привет<привет'.replace(/(?<= |<)привет/g, 'пока'));
```